# Is there any pattern in this number sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-systems

I have a feeling that it's obvious but I can't find it. I was wondering if anybody else could decode this cryptic thing.

$[1,2,4,7,10,14,19,24,30,37]$

This is very important, I hope someone can see something that I can't.

Also if possible, try to construct an algorithm that can actually predict the one, because I doubt I would have much luck with that either.

Comment: [Well...](http://oeis.org/search?q=1,2,4,7,10,14,19,24,30,37)

Comment: maybe there's a zero at the beginning, then this would work: +1,+1,+2,+3,+3,+4,+5,+5,+6,+7,+7,+8,+9,+9... so all odd numbers twice :) rather random. could you add some more numbers?

Comment: This would depend critically on where you found this sequence or how it arised.

Comment: Why not simply try OEIS or wolfram-alpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2C2%2C4%2C7%2C10%2C14%2C19%2C24%2C30%2C37%2C...

Comment: Since there are 10 numbers, you can find a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree at most $9$ so that $a_n=P(n)$. Then, there also exists uncountably many functions $f(x)$ so that $a_n=f(n)$.... Is this the type of pattern you are looking for? ;)

Comment: Oh..my..god!ALEX YOUR A GENIUS! You just solved my problem for the third level, now i gotta boggle my mind over the fourth D:.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the first and second differences of the given data:
$$\matrix{
1&&2&&4&&7&&10&&14&&19&&24&&30&&37 \cr
&1&&2&&3&&3&&4&&5&&5&&6&&7&\cr
&&1&&1&&0&&1&&1&&0&&1&&1&&\cr}$$
Here the third line seems periodic with period $3$ with mean ${2\over3}$. Therefore the given data $(y_k)_{0\leq k\leq9}$ can be produced by a function $k\mapsto f(k)$ of the form
$$f(k)={1\over3} k^2 + a\ k+ b+ c\ \cos{2k\pi\over3}+ d\ \sin{2k\pi\over3}\ .$$
Now fix the undetermined coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ such that for $k=0,\ldots,3$ the correct values $y_k$ are produced. The final result  is
$$y_k={1\over3}k^2 + k + {7\over9} + {2\over9} \cos{2k\pi\over3}\qquad(0\leq k\leq9)\ .$$

Comment: I dont understand that cryptic thing :/ Sorry i am not very advanced into mathematics.

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of mathematica is that? I never saw it before. Which part of mathematics does it come under?

Comment: @aayush: The $y_k$ satisfy the linear inhomogeneous difference equation $y_{k+2}-2y_{k+1}+y_k=$ a given periodic function of period $3$. The general theory about such equations says that our "Ansatz" with undetermined $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ works in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The [On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org) has a few results for this sequence.